# decrypt PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES encrypted string in .net

Tags: java, c#, encryption, .net-core

I need to decrypt strings that have been generate in Java with org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor that is using the PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES algorithm. I think I have found the source code here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBEWithMD5AndTripleDESCipher.java

It has some information about the algorithm:

> 1. Create random salt and split it in two halves. If the two halves are    identical, invert one of them.
> 2. Concatenate password with each of the halves.
> 3. Digest each concatenation with c iterations, where c is the    iterationCount. Concatenate the output from each digest round with the
>    password, and use the result as the input to the next digest
>    operation.    The digest algorithm is MD5.
> 4. After c iterations, use the 2 resulting digests as follows:    The 16 bytes of the first digest and the 1st 8 bytes of the 2nd digest
>    form the triple DES key, and the last 8 bytes of the 2nd digest form
>    the    IV.

The code in Java seems pretty straight forward. This is how a key is decrypted.

```
    StrongTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
    textEncryptor.setPassword(key1);
    String result = textEncryptor.decrypt(key2);
```

This is an example I have generated:

```
key1=17EXGCnC
key2=7bALjokBDuxopB+Z37DwiTX/jg3/pjUoKW4q25uzd34=
result=-1,-1
```

Can anyone guide me in how I should implement the decrypt code?

This is the package used in Java: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.melloware/jasypt/1.9.4

Comment: The code is confusing because you really have a key and encrypted data.  Key2 is the encrypted data.  To decrypt you should have a key and and encrypted message.  You have only one parameter to your decrypt method.

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't figure out how to do it. Maybe I should write that the c# code is there to show that I have started to look at it but as you are saying haven't come far.

Comment: See following. You need three things 1) Public key 2) Private Key 3) Encrypted data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.createdecryptor?view=net-5.0

Comment: @jdweng: You are only confusing things. This is not an instance of public key (asymmetric) cryptography, so there is no public and private key involved.

Comment: Perhaps [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20571685/238704) will be of value.

Comment: That Java code uses PBKDF1 it seems. If that's correct then you should be able to use [`PasswordDeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes?view=net-5.0). Of course, MD5 with 1000 iterations can hardly be said to be "strong", but yeah.

Comment: The posted sample data can not be decrypted with the posted Java/Jasypt code! Please complete the Java snippet with working sample data. What version of Jasypt are you using?

Comment: @Topaco, I have added a screenshoot from my debugger session showing the same keys. This is the package used: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.melloware/jasypt/1.9.4

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I am a bit confused the MD5 iterations and random salt. Where did you find the information of 1000 iterations and how can the salt be random? Don't I need to know the salt in order to be able to decrypt it later?

Comment: The ciphertext can be decrypted on my machine only with the Jasypt versions of the [melloware fork](https://github.com/melloware/jasypt), not with the [original versions](https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt). It seems that the implementations are different.

Comment: @user568327 Looked up the source, was a bit amazed that the iteration count was not given in your source. You should upgrade to a more secure protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted ciphertext has a length of 32 bytes with a plaintext length of 5 bytes (or 8 bytes including the padding). According to the Jasypt source code, concatenation takes place in the order *salt | IV | ciphertext*, where the salt is 8 bytes long and the IV 16 bytes.
A 16 bytes long IV makes no sense in the context of TripleDES with a block size of 8 bytes and is not used at all during decryption. In other words, the IV could be replaced in the ciphertext by any 16 bytes sequence and the decrypted plaintext would still be the same.

---

So for decryption salt, IV and ciphertext must be separated, the IV can be discarded.

The description of the key/IV derivation function is already posted in the question. An example of an implementation looks like this:

```
private static byte[] GetKeyIV(String password, byte[] salt, int count)
{
    // Decode passwort
    byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    // Split salt in 2 parts
    byte[] salt1 = new byte[4];
    byte[] salt2 = new byte[4];
    Array.Copy(salt, 0, salt1, 0, salt1.Length);
    Array.Copy(salt, 4, salt2, 0, salt2.Length);

    // Reverse 1st part if both parts are equal
    if (salt1.SequenceEqual(salt2))
    {
        Array.Reverse(salt1, 0, salt1.Length);
    }

    // Calculate 1st hash
    byte[] hash1 = salt1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        MD5 md = MD5.Create();
        hash1 = md.ComputeHash(Concatenate(hash1, pwd));
    }

    // Calculate 2nd hash
    byte[] hash2 = salt2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        MD5 md = MD5.Create();
        hash2 = md.ComputeHash(Concatenate(hash2, pwd));
    }

    // Join both hashes
    return Concatenate(hash1, hash2);
}

private static byte[] Concatenate(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[arr1.Length + arr2.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arr1, 0, bytes, 0, arr1.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(arr2, 0, bytes, arr1.Length, arr2.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

As key for TripleDES the first 24 bytes are used, as IV the last 8 bytes.

This allows decryption with the usual MS pattern:

```
// Separate data
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String("7bALjokBDuxopB+Z37DwiTX/jg3/pjUoKW4q25uzd34=");
byte[] salt = new byte[8];
byte[] ciphertext = new byte[data.Length - salt.Length - 16];
Array.Copy(data, 0, salt, 0, salt.Length);
Array.Copy(data, salt.Length + 16, ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length);

// Derive key and IV
byte[] keyIV = GetKeyIV("17EXGCnC", salt, 1000); // count = 1000 according to Jasypt sources
byte[] key = new byte[24];
byte[] iv = new byte[8];
Array.Copy(keyIV, 0, key, 0, key.Length);
Array.Copy(keyIV, key.Length, iv, 0, iv.Length);

// Decrypt
string plaintext = "";
using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    aesAlg.Key = key;
    aesAlg.IV = iv;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(ciphertext))
    {
        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
            {
                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(plaintext);
```

which gives the result of the Java code: *-1,-1*

---

Please note, that *PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES* is an outdated algorithm that should only be used for compatibility reasons.
The key derivation is not very secure using MD5 and also an iteration count of 1000 is too small. Instead, a more reliable key derivation function such as PBKDF2 should be used.
TripleDES is also outdated and inperformant and should be replaced by a more modern algorithm like AES.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you! It was also easy to implement the encrypt method based on your code. The encryption isn't that important. It is used to send clients a key with two ids hidden in the key, that they use in another request to fetch data. I have no idea why they went with this solution instead of just accepting the ids in the request but I need to be backward compatible since clients now have the key and I need to be able to send them correct data.